# React Installation Issue cannot find module

Tags: reactjs

When i install react is shows this error

```
NIMRA\AppData\Roaming\npm\' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1147
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\AMMAR\node_modules\create-react-app\index.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1144:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:985:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:135:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

Comment: #1 Node and npm version?  #2 Your log is not of npm install. Share only the log of npm install. Share your package.json